# how to handle adapter in MVP pattern

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, mvp

I'm going to create my first real MVP app. the problem that i have is with adapter. i have a button on my recyclerview card which i implement the onclick method in adapter and now the problem is with adapter. i don't know why when i implement the view interface that i made it in the presenter part of my app. i get error while i want to pass view to presenter.
this is my error

[image]

this is what everything that i did:
in my fragment:

```
public class FavoritFragment extends Fragment implements FavoritePresenter.View{
    View rootView;


    FavoritePresenter favoritePresenter;
    public FavoritFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_address, container, false);
        rootView=view;
        favoritePresenter=new FavoritePresenter(this);

        favoritePresenter.getAddressSearchModel();

    return view;
    }



    @Override
    public void updateFavoriteRecycler(ArrayList<AddressSearchModel> info) {

        RecyclerView recyclerView=(RecyclerView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.address_recyclerview);
        FavoriteAdapter adapterClass;
        adapterClass=new FavoriteAdapter(info,getActivity(),rootView);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager LayoutManager= new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(LayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new
                DividerItemDecoration(rootView.getContext(),LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterClass);
        adapterClass.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteFavorite(ArrayList<AddressSearchModel> id) {

    }

}
```

in my presenter

```
public class FavoritePresenter {
    // use this class to make networkCall Catch data and so on
    View view;

    ArrayList<AddressSearchModel> addressSearchModel;
    public FavoritePresenter(View view){
        this.view=view;
        addressSearchModel=new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void getAddressSearchModel()
    {
        addressSearchModel=PreparData();
        view.updateFavoriteRecycler(this.addressSearchModel);
    }
    /**
     *   do the network call and delete favorite and then do another network call to update it.
     *      The better ways is to catch data and sort it base on update field and then send update field
     *   to ruby part and in ruby take the rest of field base on update_at field (better performance)
     */
    public void deleteFavorite(AddressSearchModel favoriteId){
        addressSearchModel=deleteData();
        view.deleteFavorite(this.addressSearchModel);
    }
    private ArrayList<AddressSearchModel> deleteData() {
        ArrayList<AddressSearchModel> lst_SearchResult=new ArrayList<>();;
        AddressSearchModel model=new AddressSearchModel();
        model.setName("sasd");
        model.setAddress("sdsaqweqweqwds");
        model.setRegions("asdfdgdfgqweqwedfasgfad");
        model.setWorkingHours("2412312312");
        model.setTelephone("22211111");

        lst_SearchResult.add(model);
        model=new AddressSearchModel();
        model.setName("sas21312dqweqwe");
        model.setAddress("sdsaderers");
        model.setRegions("asdfdgdfgdfasgfad");
        model.setWorkingHours("2412312312");
        model.setTelephone("22211111");
        lst_SearchResult.add(model);





        return lst_SearchResult;
    }
    //call network call using this method to update recyclerview
    private ArrayList<AddressSearchModel> PreparData() {
        ArrayList<AddressSearchModel> lst_SearchResult=new ArrayList<>();;
        AddressSearchModel model=new AddressSearchModel();
        model.setName("sasd");
        model.setAddress("sdsads");
        model.setRegions("asdfdgdfgdfasgfad");
        model.setWorkingHours("2412312312");
        model.setTelephone("22211111");

        lst_SearchResult.add(model);
        model=new AddressSearchModel();
        model.setName("sas21312d");
        model.setAddress("sdsaderers");
        model.setRegions("asdfdgdfgdfasgfad");
        model.setWorkingHours("2412312312");
        model.setTelephone("22211111");
        lst_SearchResult.add(model);

        model=new AddressSearchModel();
        model.setName("saweresd");
        model.setAddress("sdsererads");
        model.setRegions("asdfdgererdfgdfasgfad");
        model.setWorkingHours("2412312312");
        model.setTelephone("22211111");
        lst_SearchResult.add(model);


        return lst_SearchResult;
    }
    public interface  View
    {
        void updateFavoriteRecycler(ArrayList<AddressSearchModel>  info);

        //i get String as id because of UUID type format in ruby on rails
        void deleteFavorite(ArrayList<AddressSearchModel> id);
    }
}
```

and in my adapter:

```
public class FavoriteAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FavoriteAdapter.MyHolder> implements FavoritePresenter.View {
    private List<AddressSearchModel> doctorList;
    public Activity activity;
    public View rootView;
    public FavoriteAdapter(List<AddressSearchModel> doctorList, Activity activity,View view)
    {
        rootView=view;
        this.activity=activity;
        this.doctorList=doctorList;
    }




    class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public ImageView mArticleImage;
        public TextView drugstore_desc;
        public Button DeleteFavorite;
        public MyHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mArticleImage=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.im_article);
            drugstore_desc=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.drugstore_desc);
            DeleteFavorite=(Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.DeleteFavorite);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.cardview_address_montakhab,parent,false);

        return new MyHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyHolder holder, final int position) {
        final AddressSearchModel addressSearchModel =doctorList.get(position);
        Log.d("Doctore_Size", String.valueOf(doctorList.size()));
        //holder.ImageView.setText(addressSearchModel.getName());
        holder.drugstore_desc.setText(addressSearchModel.getRegions());

        holder.DeleteFavorite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                fav_GetAddress(addressSearchModel.getName(), addressSearchModel.getRegions());
                FavoritePresenter favoritePresenter=new FavoritePresenter(v);
                favoritePresenter.deleteFavorite(addressSearchModel);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteFavorite(ArrayList<AddressSearchModel> id) {

    }
    @Override
    public void updateFavoriteRecycler(ArrayList<AddressSearchModel> info) {
        RecyclerView recyclerView=(RecyclerView)activity.findViewById(R.id.address_recyclerview);
        FavoriteAdapter adapterClass;
        adapterClass=new FavoriteAdapter(info,activity,rootView);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager LayoutManager= new LinearLayoutManager(activity);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(LayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new
                DividerItemDecoration(activity,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterClass);
        adapterClass.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public  void fav_GetAddress(String place,String PlaceAddress){
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_add_address);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.draw_radius_cost_info);
        // set the custom dialog components - text, image and draw_button
        EditText placeName=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.placeName);
        EditText StreetAddress=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.StreetAddress);

        placeName.setText(place);
        StreetAddress.setText(PlaceAddress);

        TextView dialogButton = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogOK);
        // if draw_button is clicked, close the custom dialog
        dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
// custom dialog

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return doctorList.size();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`View v` inside `onClick` is of type `android.view.View`, while your `FavoritePresenter` is expecting a `FavoritePresenter.View`. To fix, create `FavoritePresenter` instance passing along `FavoritePresenter.View` type:

```
    holder.DeleteFavorite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            fav_GetAddress(addressSearchModel.getName(), addressSearchModel.getRegions());
            FavoritePresenter favoritePresenter=new FavoritePresenter(FavoriteAdapter.this);
            favoritePresenter.deleteFavorite(addressSearchModel);
        }
    });
```

Comment: thanks alot it works well but without select() function, what is that method for

Comment: Sorry that was not supposed to be there, edited it out